# Об умниках и умницах

Tags: словообразование

Есть, кажется, такая телепередача (или еще что-то) - "Умники и умницы". То есть, соответственно, речь идет об умных представителях обоих полов. Но в быту чаще даже по отношению к мужчине можно услышать "умница", а вот "умник" звучит уже как-то, мягко скажем, иронично.
Та же ситуация со словом "молодЕц". Понятно, что это форма мужского рода. А как в таком случае похвалить девушку?
И третий пример - слово "бедняк". Оно тоже относится исключительно к мужчине. А как же одним словом обозначить бедную женщину?

Answer (score 1):

Умница и молодЕц – слова общего рода.
А "бедняк" – мужского. Одним словом назвать бедную женщину не получается.

Answer (score 0):

Я хочу дополнить ответ user3758. Бедная женщина это беднячка, нищая, нищенка